# Rendering multiple types of media

Tags: iphone, multimedia

One of the requirements for my iPhone application is that it will be handed multiple types of data from a server: audio, video, text, and image animation. All of the media will come together as a bundle, and depending on the bundle contents, the application needs to render the appropriate media types.

Example: If the bundle contains animation content, it will render and play the animation; if it contains video, it will play the video, etc.

Is there any standardized protocol or way of handling this?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at UIWebView.

```
UIWebView *view = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSString *html = @"<html><body>CUSTOMIZE YOUR CONTENT APPEARANCE HERE</body></html>";
[view loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:nil]];
```

Inside `<body> <`/body> tags you should create an html content, which will include your graphics and videos. But I'm not sure about sound. It is possible that you will have to play it manually. Maybe you will want to read http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/playing-short-sounds-in-objective-c-iphone-sdk/

Comment: thanks. that seems to be a feasible mechanism. But what i wanted to know about is, i need some authoring tool where i add all the files, and when iphone browses them, categorically deides what to do with them !

Comment: @user705737: As I understand you want one view with a lot of content previews. And when user selects one of them the corresponding content is viewed in some other view. If yes you should implement it by yourself. Maybe a UIScrollView with a lot of UIImageView in it will make some sense. If you need to browse files in file system please take a look at NSFileManager class.